# div isn't centering , one div is one div is not

Tags: html, css

Demo Page: http://apps.pc-tips.in/play/

In the above, the div containing "Ask any question & get" is centered, but the div containg the line "answers on" is not.  why? Both have been styled similarly. given width, absolute position, margin auto.

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
div {
    margin:0 ;
    padding:0 ;
}
#sidebar {
    height: 600px;
    width: 200px;
}

#topside {
    height: 108px;
    background-image: url(Untitled-3.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
.down {
    bottom: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    width: 200px;

}
#bottomside {
    background-image: url(Untitled-4.jpg);
    height: 492px;
    position: relative;
}
#wrapper #sidebar #topside {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.delhi {
    font-size: 1.8em;
}
.top {
    top: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100px;

}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="sidebar">
      <div id="topside"><br /> <span class="delhi">Delhi </span> Questions and answers.
     <div class="down">
    Ask any question & get  
    </div>
      </div>
      <div id="bottomside">
      <div class="top"> answers on </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

would anyone like to point out what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As kuroir's answer says, you can't center elements this way if you're also using absolute positioning.

Your "ask any question" div *isn't* being centered, you've given it the same width as its container.

The only reason the two look different is that there's a `text-align: center` on the `#topside` container, and not on the `#bottomside` container.

Comment: Thanks all , text-align center did it. also it now seems obvious that margin: 0 auto; won't center an absolute div..

Answer (score 1):

You can't center an element via `margin:0 auto` when it has `position:absolute` added to it. Remove the `position:absolute` from `.top` and it should work.

Not sure what you're trying to achieve, but this pretty much solves the problem you have. Remember you can use padding to "center" contents. That will save you from having to set the width explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your CSS, updating the '#bottomside' and '.top' styles like so:

```
#bottomside {
background-image: url(Untitled-4.jpg);
height: 492px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
}

.top {
top: 3px;
position: absolute;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 100%;
}
```

The changes are self explanatory, if there is a confusion, let me know.

Comment: on a sidenote, you can optimize your css a fair bit, removing items / styles that are not really required, but that's something you can look into later! :)